# Meaning of "count for" in "count for sixty-five percent of all total funds"

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Whereas in the past the tourist board put in the majority of funding, now public donations **count for** sixty-five percent of all total funds!

What does "count for" mean in this context?

Comment: Most people would actually use ***account for*** in the cited context. See [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which+account+for+over%2Cwhich+count+for+over&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhich%20account%20for%20over%3B%2Cc0) for ***...which [ac]count for over [half of the total]***.

Comment: Is that from an interview? Probably a transcription error for account.

Answer (score 1):

This means that 65 % of the total funds are the public donations.

For example -

> **a** counts for 60 percent of **This**, while **b** counts for 40 percent of **This**.

means that **This** comprises of 60 % a and 40 % b.

See the third definition for the intransitive verb form [here](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/count).

Comment: So is it the same as " account for "but actually I don't find this meaning for it in dictionaries (Oxford and Longman).

Comment: @user87080 It is in some dictionaries.